# I am declaring a function, but it is non callable, why?

Tags: node.js

I am declaring a function using Node.js, but it is being non callable.

I do not understand what is wrong since I declared it as the same way as the other functions and this is the only one that is being non callable.

My code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const mainKey = '';
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "hotels"
});



function getUsers() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var users = new Array();
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        con.query(sql, function(err, result, fields) {
            if(err) throw err;
            users = [];
            for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++) {
                users.push([result[i].id, result[i].user, result[i].password]);
            }
            resolve(users);
        });
    });
}

function regUser(user, password, key) {  //this function is non callable
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log(test)
    });
}

function getHotelNames(idUser) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var hotelNames = new Array();
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE user=" + idUser;
        con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            hotelNames = [];
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                hotelNames.push(escape(result[i].name));                      
            }
            resolve(hotelNames);
        });
    })
}

function getURLs() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var urlsHotels = new Array();
        const sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            urlsHotels = [];
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                urlsHotels.push(result[i].url);                        
            }
            resolve(urlsHotels);
        });
    })
}

function insertValues(hotelNames, url, name, idUser) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const id = hotelNames.length+1
        const sql = "INSERT INTO hotels (id, name, url, user) VALUES (" + id + ", '" + name + "', '" + url + "', " + idUser +")";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err)  resolve(['errorNewHotel']); //throw err;
            resolve(['NewHotel'])
        });
    })
}

function deleteValues(name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const sql = "DELETE FROM hotels WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
        console.log(sql)
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err)  resolve(['errorDeletingHotel']); //throw err;
            resolve(['deletedHotel'])
        });
    })
}

const funcGetUsers = async ()=> {
    const users = await getUsers();
    return users;
}

const funcRegisterUser = async (user, password, key)=> {
    const regUser = await regUser(user, password, key); //I am calling the function here
    return regUser;
}

const funcGetHotelNames = async (idUser)=> {
    const hotelNames = await getHotelNames(idUser);
    return hotelNames;
}

const funcGetURLs = async ()=> {
    const urls = await getURLs();
    return urls;
}

const funcInsertValues = async(hotelNames, url, name, idUser)=> {
    const message = await insertValues(hotelNames, url, name, idUser);
    return message;
}

const funcDeleteValues = async(name)=> {
    const message = await deleteValues(name);
    return message;
}

module.exports.funcGetUsers = funcGetUsers;
module.exports.funcRegisterUser = funcRegisterUser;
module.exports.funcGetHotelNames = funcGetHotelNames;
module.exports.funcGetURLs = funcGetURLs;
module.exports.funcInsertValues = funcInsertValues;
module.exports.funcDeleteValues = funcDeleteValues;
```

Even my code editor, Visual Studio Code says it is never read
[image]

That is what I get when I try to run function:

[image]

I do not think the issue comes from the main file (server.js), so I have tried to copy all the code in a new file and Visual Studio was still saying that it is never read while the other functions were fine.

What am I doing wrong? I do not get it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real Javascript error is:

> ReferenceError: regUser is not defined

In

```
const funcRegisterUser = async (user, password, key)=> {
    const regUser = await regUser(user, password, key); //I am calling the function here
    return regUser;
}
```

You're trying to assign to a variable named `regUser` *while also* calling a function named `regUser`. But, because you declare a variable named `regUser` inside that function, any references to a variable named `regUser` inside that function will refer to that `regUser` variable. So your `await regUser(...)` is trying to `await` the variable which has not been assigned to yet - it's in the temporal dead zone.

Just use a different variable name, and you'll avoid the name collision:

```
const funcRegisterUser = async (user, password, key)=> {
    const result = await regUser(user, password, key);
    return result;
}
```

Or, just return the Promise itself, no need to `await` something you immediately return:

```
const funcRegisterUser = (user, password, key) => (
    regUser(user, password, key)
);
```

Or, even better, since `funcRegisterUser` is just calling `regUser`, maybe leave out `funcRegisterUser` entirely, and just export `regUser`:

```
module.exports.funcRegisterUser = regUser;
```

Comment: Ok, I couldn't imagine that was the issue. Now I return the Promise itself and it's working. Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the function, but how you call it.

```
const regUser = await regUser(user, password, key);
```

This line will create a new constant `regUser` as `undefined`, then try to invoke it as a function. Your function is shadowed in outer scope, and thus inaccessible. The solution is simple: change the name of your constant.